# How fast 3D rendering a still image per client request, in server can be made?

Tags: web-services, 3d, render

I am trying to make a service that needs to quickly render simple 3D scenes on the server, and then return them as a JPEG.  It should be able to accommodate mass users (client) so that it serve rendered image per client request.  User->HTML->Server->(perhaps renderfarm)->Result display.

Is current technology able to give a return really quickly like in 5 seconds, after it renders 3D scene like clothes ??

Thanks.

Comment: This really depends on how fast your server(s) are and what your expectations are of the render. Any cursory glance at rendering software will show a whole list of parameters for changing the quality of the render.

Answer (score 0):

The deeper your pockets the faster it goes(crawls, fly, traveling at warp speed)! 
But if you asking something like "Can i build render farm for realtime raytrace renderer  with 1000$ in pocket?" Then NO - Technology not yet here(or there).

Comment: Shouldn't be there yet.  Hope, hooking up renderfarm service would cut down entry cost.

Answer (score 0):

A naive solution I made 5 years ago using DirectX and nVidia GPUs could respond to 20 requests a second per server while loading resources on the fly. We were limited to 32 bits hardware so we didn't have enough memory to hold all the commonly used resources in process memory, therefore, resource management was the bottleneck.

For a particular client, we were using 5 machines behind a big-ip which would account to what I estimate as a small amount of the project's budget.

With todays 64 bits memory space and more powerful GPUs, yes, it is very possible to do something small to medium scale without spending much more than the price of a couple of PCs.

Comment: Sounds very hopeful.  Can you get me some guides or advice of what to look at and etc.?? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

it depend also from where are you loading your models and textures.... if they are yours and you load them from your server then should work fast....the server side software which will generate the rendered image also can affect the time depending how fast it will prepare the scene.
Next problem is the server capabilities and of course client net connection speed :)

Comment: Yeah.  You can suppose models and textures are all sitting in a server.  I should find time it delays in a server software as request scales.